# Creating DDNS with udhcpd and PowerDNS

Tags: dns, dhcpd

- **Server OS** = Ubuntu 12.0.4.1 LTS
- **Desktop OS** = Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
- **DHCP Server daemon** = udhcp
- **DNS Server daemon** = powerdns (using mysql as the backend)

I am very new to the Linux scene, been playing with it for the past 2 weeks, I have sifted through many web pages and articles and I am extremely impressed and thankful with the Linux community's willingness to share their knowledge.

What I am really battling to find is a website / article that can explain how to setup
udhcp so that every time a lease is granted an entry into the dns server is made and when a lease is revoked that entry is then deleted.

It would be appreciated if the answers could include some examples as to how I can implement it.

Thank you
Mark Hollander
Linux newbie (only for the moment)

Comment: Looking at the udhcpd.conf file I see there is an option notify_file. I am presuming that I can place the location to the script to be executed here. If that is the case, how would I know if: 1) udhcpd is assigning a lease or releasing a lease 2) What ip-address and mac-address the action is being performed on.

Comment: I have chosen to abandon this route and go with an article that I have found on the net using the isc-dhcp server instead. I have a few problems with that route which I will post as a new question/thread.